# Ошибка ClassNotFoundException на стороне клиента при десериализации

Tags: java, netbeans

Пишу приложение, которое производит обмен данными по протоколу UDP. Сервер и клиент в разных проектах. Передается экземпляр некоего класса, который находится в одном проекте с сервером. Перед отправкой экземпляр сериализуется. При десериализации на стороне клиента ошибка `ClassNodFoundException`, хотя клиент имеет собственную копию кода пересылаемого класса. 
Спасибо.

> `java1.pkg2.pkg2.Listener.main(Listener.java:27)java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java1.pkg2.Person
>     at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
>     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>     at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
>     at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
>     at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
>     at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:247)
>     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.resolveClass(ObjectInputStream.java:603)
>     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1574)
>     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1495)
>     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1731)
>     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1328)
>     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:350)
>     at java1.pkg2.pkg2.Listener.main(Listener.java:27)`

Comment: Дайте стектрейс.

Comment: Ну да, какой-то из нужных классов отсутствует в `classpath`. *Почему это происходит, вам придется подумать самому.*

Comment: Что значит "клиент имеет собственную копию кода пересылаемого класса"? Полностью квалифицированные имена классов совпадают?

Comment: а чем вам RMI не угодил ?

Answer (score 2):

В случае, когда происходит десериализация дерева объектов, то все классы соответствующих объектов должны быть доступны через `CLASSPATH` в рантайме. *Предполагаю, что в вашем случае этого не происходит или по каким-то причинам происходит, но не для всех классов, которые десериализуются.*

*Неплохо бы посмотреть стектрейс*, но это - наиболее вероятная причина `ClassNotFoundException`.

---

Можно конечно допустить, что суть ошибки сложнее, как, например, происходит [**здесь,**](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/XSTR-185) однако я очень в этом сомневаюсь.

Answer (score 1):

> собственную копию кода

Вы хотите сказать, что у вас 2 копии пересылаемого класса `Person` - на клиенте и на сервере? Хм, ну это вообще-то все равно должно сработать (хотя это и в корне неправильно) - если только у вас не разные пакеты для `Person` на клиенте и на сервере (к этой мысли подталкивает тот факт, что в `java1.pkg2.pkg2.Listener` на клиенте мы пытаемся десериализовать `java1.pkg2.Person`.

Comment: простите за ламерство) действительно проблема в этом, решила, что клиент и сервер должны быть в разных приложениях, соответственно вылилось вот в такую неразбериху.

Comment: А что делать, если разные пакеты?

Comment: 1) сделать пакеты одинаковыми, 2) использовать альтернативную сериализацию, например, json/XML.